# How to extend vtiger expression for workflows?

Tags: expression, vtiger

how can I extend vtiger expression to have more function in a workflow?

What I found so far is to modify core files, which get updated probably on updates of vtiger

- modules/com_vtiger_workflow/expression_engine/VTExpressionsManager.inc
- modules/com_vtiger_workflow/expression_engine/VTExpressionEvaluater.inc

so for me it is not clear what the best practice is if:

I do not want to modify the given files?
e.g.

- class extending (inheritance)
- registering via database
- or other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a new .inc file with your code and call it from:

modules/com_vtiger_workflow/expression_engine/include.inc

Then in case that file get overwrited in an update, you only have to include again the require_once on the include.inc

No the cleanest way, but quick and easy. ;-)

Comment: do you have an working example? Cannot see how you extend the according function?

Comment: Hello. Sorry I don't have sample code, it was just an idea. What specific expression do you want to extend or what new expression do you want to code?

Comment: you can use any sample code for this. E.g. create a new invoice number from current quotenumber and date. For me it is crucial to know how to avoid core file changes at all

Comment: can't you just use a custom function for that? [link](https://it-solutions4you.com/tipstricks/invoke-custom-function-from-workflow-task/)

Comment: not sure, since starter at this topic...